# Using Android-Tablet as an MQTT-Server

Tags: android, push-notification, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I have read something about "messaging system" using  the MQTT protocol. But i was always reading about the constellation:
using Android as a MQTT-Client and a MQTT-Server which is not installed on a Android smartphone oder tablet (but as a standalone server).

Is it possible to use one Android-Tablet as a MQTT-Server and some other Android-Tablets (for example 5 Tablets) as MQTT-Clients??

And if this is possible, is it possible to use the one Android-Tablet which is a MQTT-Server, also as a MQTT-Client?

The communication between the Android-MQTT-Server-Tablet and the other tablets as MQTT-Client, should work over an WIFI-Router / WIFI-Access-Point.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use tablets as mqtt brokers (server) and mqtt clients. You'll have to use a client library on all tablets and a broker on one of them.

Here is pure java broker I have adapted to work on Android: https://github.com/interaktionsbyran/moquette Feel free to try it out!

Comment: I am trying to use your library on my project. However I am having hard time invoking it. I read your setup instructions (change some gradle files), but the compiler complains that Server is an unknown entity.

Comment: @Gussoh Seems like the binary file for listener is not available till 4th of July(https://bintray.com/) since BinaryTray is migrating to new platform. Can you post it somewhere else?
Also is it possible to connect the Android device (as MQTT broker) and a PC using usbc-ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible.

The hard bit would be working out which tablet would become the broker. One approach would be to use avahi (mDNS) to try and discover a broker, if none are found then set one up and advertise it via avahi.

As for actually finding a broker that will run on Android that would be anther challenge. I'm not aware of a public pure Java broker available, but you may be able to get mosquitto to compile as a native (arm) Android app, but you would need to write a service wrapper for it.

Comment: I have subsequently learned that HiveMQ (https://github.com/hivemq) is a pure java MQTT server you may be able to use

Comment: HiveMQ is a closed source solution, hence not acceptable for our use case. We have experience with mosquitto and wrapping into a service sounds promising. Do you have any experience with running mosquitto as such on Android? Or any pointers?

Comment: Another argument for using mosquitto is the support

Comment: I had success with the Server Ultimate app. They will ask for you to download the server pack B. I runned just fine, but about embedding it to an app it is another history.