# Deploying MQTT broker on Android?

Tags: android, mqtt, iot

I see that a lot of questions about deploying a MQTT broker on Android get asked about their purpose and eventually get voted down. Is it not a good idea to run the broker on the phone so that IoT devices could talk directly to the phone without going through some cloud server? Otherwise how else could the devices talk to the phone in an "offline" setting? Yes, the phone will have to be in range, of course. Will the phone have to be in hotspot mode?

Comment: It seems to be agreed it is possible here (no visible down votes...): http://stackoverflow.com/q/19114730/334402. If this is for something like events etc where you also have the option of running the broker on a laptop this might be easier as it would be closer to a 'regular server'. You could have a separate WiFi access point or even use a phone as a WiFi hotspot to connect everything (bearing in mind you will need some sort of IP address discovery or local DNS resolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must exist a major reason to have a Broker embedded in a mobile client and not in a server.

The rationale is that you have the broker running in a server, then several mobile clients exchange messages by connecting to the Broker and publishing and subscribing to specific topics in the server broker.

Client x (Mobile) <-msgs-> Broker (Server) <-msgs-> Client y (Mobile)

Comment: Curiosity could be one of the reasons.
There might be some even practical, say someone might want to connect a mobile sensor reader to a mobile MQTT server.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution. My reason is to run the broker on a Nexus 10 tablet which is online all the time anyway. No need for a separate server or a cloud service (beware!).

Answer (score 1):

There are possibilities with broker running on Android , since with Android things (IoT for Android),

> I have made an App -
>   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=server.com.mqtt&hl=en

People are using it in their projects without any issues

Comment: instead of promoting your application. can you help in how you did it?

Comment: I tried this application, its configuration was pretty straight forward, so I got my desktop client connected to the Android server, in under two minutes. Simply works!
(Although the capabilities of the application are somewhat limited, I think...)